# shp2pgsql: not found on Debian 10 PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgis, postgresql, debian

I have installed PostgreSQL 13 by using the following repository

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg main
```

and I have installed PostGIS using

```
apt install postgresql-13-postgis-3
```

However `shp2pgsql` is not installed on my machine. I thought about installing the `postgis` package by the following command

`apt install postgis`

However it tries to install packages related to PostgreSQL 12 instead of PostgreSQL 13 which is the version installed on my server

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgis postgis-doc postgresql-12 postgresql-12-postgis-3 postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-client-12
```

What do I need to do to get `shp2pgsql` installed?

Answer (score 3):

This is really more of a debian question than a gis question... You are right that the package postgis should install some utilities, including shp2pgsql, but since it is trying to install postgis for postgresql 12, when you have postgresql 13 installed it sounds to me as if you have some dependency issues. Did you need to give any extra arguments to install postgresql 13?

Are all your apt sources for the same debian version?

Have you tried to force postgis from buster?

apt install postgis/buster
or
apt-get install postgis -t buster

Have you been fetching postgresql packages from the postgresql repository for a long time, or may it be that there are some left overs from a standard debian postgresql installation in your system? If so try to purge those parts.

apt-cache policy  will give you an overview of what is existing and what is to be installed,

Sorry I cannot give you any definitive answers, but I hope you get some pointers to where to look.

(I have a similiar setup to yours, I have still not installed postgresql 13, but I was an early adaptor of postgresql12 with postgis and that installe without any issues as far as I remember)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the PostgreSQL repository has not added Postgis for Postgresql 13 yet since it's recent release. I switched to Postgresql 12 for the time being.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.